# error While making Website in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, dotnetnuke

I am New to dnn. I am trying to make a Website in IIS7. But this Shows a Followinf error.
HOw this error will be removed
error:

omain Name experiment Does Not Exist In The Database

DotNetNuke supports multiple portals from a single database/codebase. It accomplishes this by converting the URL of the client browser Request to a valid PortalID in the Portals database table. The following steps describe the process:

```
Web Server Processing
    When a web server receives a Request from a client browser, it compares the file name extension on the target URL resource to its Application Extension Mappings defined in IIS.
    Based on the corresponding match, IIS then sends the Request to the defined Executable Path ( aspnet_asapi.dll in the case of ASP.NET Requests ).
    The aspnet_isapi.dll engine processes the Request in an ordered series of events beginning with Application_BeginRequest.


HttpModule.URLRewrite OnBeginRequest ( UrlRewriteModule.vb )
    The Request URL is parsed based on the "/" character
    A Domain Name is constructed using each of the relevant parsed URL segments.

    Examples:

    URL: http://www.domain.com/default.aspx = Domain Name: www.domain.com
    URL: http://209.75.24.131/default.aspx = Domain Name: 209.75.24.131
    URL: http://localhost/DotNetNuke/default.aspx = Domain Name: localhost/DotNetNuke
    URL: http://www.domain.com/virtualdirectory/default.aspx = Domain Name: www.domain.com/virtualdirectory
    URL: http://www.domain.com/directory/default.aspx = Domain Name: www.domain.com/directory

    Using the Domain Name, the application queries the database ( Portals table - PortalAlias field ) to locate a matching record.

    Note: If there are multiple URLs which correspond to the same portal then the PortalAlias field must contain each valid Domain Name in a comma seperated list.

    Example:

    URL: http://localhost/DotNetNuke/default.aspx
    URL: http://MACHINENAME/DotNetNuke/default.aspx
    URL: http://209.32.134.65/DotNetNuke/default.aspx
    PortalAlias: localhost/DotNetNuke,MACHINENAME/DotNetNuke,209.32.134.65/DotNetNuke

    Note: If you are installing the application to a remote server you must modify the PortalAlias field value for the default record in the Portals table according to the rules defined above.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your are trying to host website in server where you don't have a domain called "Experiment".
Check the last line given in your question : "Note: If you are installing the application to a remote server you must modify the PortalAlias field value for the default record in the Portals table according to the rules defined above."
So check the values in PortalAlias table and specify the domain name (localhost may work).